# Why is my browser showing the wrong certificate?

Tags: networking, dns, browser, nas, ssl-certificate

I have installed wordpress on my Synology and opened up the appropriate ports on my route to expose the Synology on the internet.

1. I have purchased a domain from GoDaddy
2. I have setup a ddns using no-ip.com
3. I have setup CNAME to the dns.

The problem I am facing is that when I try to access the website from within my network (the network that contains the Synology), my browser shows certificate error 'NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID' and I see the certificate shown below.

When I access it from outside my network, I don't see this error. And when I click on the 'lock' icon I see the certificate I have installed on my Synology.

**What is wrong?** I have not seen this certificate before. Where did this come from?

Here is a screenshot of the certificate that the browser sees.

[image]

PS: I recently changed my certificate provider since my older certificate expired. I have installed the new certificate on my synology.

Comment: zi think the now deleted pist was correct - Aj im pretty sure the above explanation is correct - the routing type used by the router is "Hair pin NAT" - and that cert is issued by your router as per the organization "Technicolor". To check this hypothesis, hard-code the internal ip + domain in your hosts file - I bet that will both make the problem appear to go away and allow you to compare certs.

Comment: @davidgo Adding the entry to hosts file did the trick. PS: I don't know what happened to an earlier answer to this question.